# mssql 2003 server backup to a remote disk

Tags: sql-server, backup

is there a way to convince mssql server 2003 to allow me to backup to an external (NAS) drive rather than the current slow USB disk.

According to the docs (and certainly in practice it seems) your not able to select a device not physically attached to the server.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Ta

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating local backups that are then copied to the NAS by a script that runs at completion of the backup.

Or take a look at [this](https://forums.sdn.sap.com:443/message.jspa?messageID=7893167).  They answer your exact question.